# How to custom symbol from LaTeX symbol?

Tags: symbols

```
\bigtriangledown
```

creates
[image]

How to fill color and remove the black boundary so that I can create a customed symbol similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can find the appropriate black symbol, then it can be colored easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\[
  \triangledown
  \blacktriangledown
  \begingroup
    \color{blue}
    \blacktriangledown
  \endgroup
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the symbol is a math symbol, then the color should be set via:

```
\begingroup\color{<color>}<symbol>\endgroup
```

Curly braces and `\textcolor` would change the meaning of the math atom, which can affect the horizontal spacing.

---

The symbol in the example above seems to have the same height and width.
That means, the length of the slanted edge is sqrt(*a*<sup>2</sup> + (*a*/2)<sup>2</sup>) with *a* as height or width of the triangle. Then the horizontal scaling factor (*a* = 1) is sqrt(5)/2 ≈ 1.118034:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\isotri}[1]{%
  \scalebox{1.118034}[1]{$#1$}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \isotri\triangledown
  \isotri\blacktriangledown
  \begingroup
    \color{blue}
    \isotri\blacktriangledown
  \endgroup
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result scaled]

---

Also the symbol could be easily created by `tikz` or similar packages.
However it is not possible in TeX to get the exact information about the shape of a glyph, thus the dimensions must be measured, estimated or guessed.

Comment: shape isn't quite the same.  darn triangles!  like standards, there are so many to choose from!

Comment: @barbarabeeton The width could be stretched via `\resizebox` or `\scalebox`. The vertical position can be adjusted with `\raisebox`. Side bearings can be modified via `\kern`. At least there is no line thickness.

Answer (score 4):

A possible way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}

\begin{document}

Example: {\color{SeaGreen}\FilledBigTriangleDown}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `\textcolor{color}{thing}` in this case.